# Is "the instant you left" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Given this sentence:

> Frankly, I was deeply offended the instant you left me.

[This web page](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/instant) covers the sentence

> the instant I heard it

which is grammatically similar to the above sentence, in the Translations section, so the construction looks legitimate. I'm not sure, though.

Is the use of "the instant" correct in my example sentence?

Comment: Yes, it' fine. It's similar to "the moment". "The instant" is used in the sense of "at the exact time" etc.

Comment: It's a very interesting question.   The web site you point to (as far as I can see) only implies that its use is legitimate, but doesn't cover grammatically why.   "The instant you left me" is common (in the sense that it doesn't sound wrong) but actually I can't explain why the grammar is correct to my own satisfaction.   The sentence appears to be a contraction, actually.   It comprises a statement (I was offended) followed by a noun (the instant) without a preposition.   It's "fine" in the sense that it sounds fine, but I'm curious about what class of "acceptable" grammar it falls into!

Comment: Actually, I convinced myself it's fine and added an answer to that effect :)

Comment: It's grammatically correct.  Whether it's what you intend is harder to say.

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean in particular?

Comment: Note that the phrase "the instant you left me" would have the exact same grammatical role as "at ten-fifteen last night".

Comment: I mean I can't read your mind.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I think that's similar to my understanding. "the instant you left me" => "at the instant when you left me." I just want to ask about omitting the "at" and "when" words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be fine on the grounds that statements about time are fine to have an abstract noun representing the time, following main clause.

For example, "I am fine today".

This has the same grammar as "I was offended yesterday", which has the same grammar as "I was offended the instant you left me".